# Android Design Guidelines

Tags: android-layout, android, android-developer-api

I am doing a new Android App and need to know the latest design guidelines or methodology.
Can any one help me with useful links. As I have created almost 8 apps but not sure of designs and I googled a lot about it but still dint get thro any clear conclusion.

Thannx In advance

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

Comment: See this book, helped me a lot http://www.androiddesignbook.com/android-design-patterns-interaction-design-solutions-for-developers/

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html Go through this link